# Changing classes and saving images with summernote

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, wysiwyg, summernote

I was wondering if it possible to change the class of an image tag gotten from summernote.

Currently I am using summernote with rails4 and have implemented it the following way:

in creation of a new project

```
<%= form_for(@project, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :description, id:"summernote" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote();
    });
</script>
```

and when I show it

```
<%= @project.description.html_safe %>
```

If I insert an image like this it works but i would like to know two things:
1: Where does this image get stored? If I look at the source code generate it is just data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4S/(Bunch of random letters)

2:I would like give a class to all  tags generated for images uploaded with summernote (and possibly save them using paperclip if possible)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. The "f.text_area" in your code will hold everything you enter in the summernote box entry. Once you submit the entry all images will be converted to base64 and stored directly in your database end server.
2. To apply your own tags on the images click on the "Code View" button found in summernote editing toolbar and locate your image code then manually place an opening `<div class= "your-class">` before the image code and another closing `<div>` tag after your image code.

Comment: Is there any way to do it, so that everytime I add an image using summernote, that custom class gets added to it?